# Websites that focus on widgets

Tags: app-widgets

I see a lot of sites that focus on apps, but where are the sites that focus on widgets?

For example, I'm trying to find an agenda widget that doesn't hurt my eyes, but it's really hard trying to sort out everything from a Google search. A widget gallery type of site would be nice.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not entirely what you're asking for, but have you tried using [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com)? It usually does the trick for me in finding any sort of app, widgets included. The screenshots are helpful.

To the secondary (not quite asked) question, I find [Android Agenda Widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.roflharrison.agenda.plus) to be very easy on the eyes and highly themeable.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [My Color Screen](http://mycolorscreen.com/). It's a customization site, so it focuses on launchers, themes, and widgets. Because of that focus, you might find it's too much about the appearance of the widget instead of the functionality, but it might be just what you're looking for.